# How do I get CodeIgniter sessions to work accross multiple applications?

Tags: codeigniter, session

I use two different applications in my CI installation.  The first is called "admin"... obviously an admin panel.  The second is "frontend" where everything else is.  I use the same database for each of the apps and the same member tables, both for admin authentication and member auth.  The problem is, since the CI session class doesn't use native PHP sessions, the session only works in the application that it is set in(which makes sense)... for example, if a user that is indeed an admin logs into the system through the frontend app and then clicks the link to the admin app, they are required to login again.  If they have the "Remember Me" option selected across when they login to both apps, this obviously isn't a problem.

How would I fix this?  Or do you guys think it's better to have them login to the admin app again, just to validate their admin status again?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are the apps on the same domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the native php session instead. There's a [class](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Native-session) which you can just copy paste, and you'll not have to change any of the rest of your code.

Comment: I actually debated for a while on whether or not I should go that route... I figured there must be a way with the regular CI session class, but it was such a headache to figure out that I decided to go with the native sessions class.

Comment: Last time I used the CI session, I had an issue with it (I don't remember what exactly) so I switched to native sessions and only added one function that had a conflict. By now, I think it most probably has been fixed.